# Extracting rasters multi-value to points

Tags: python, raster, point, extract

I have a point shapefile and 90000 raster files with precipitation data. For each point, I tried extracting precipitation data from the rasters to points (gauge stations) using ArcGIS model builder, but failed because it worked only for 1000 rasters.

Can you please help me to find another solution using a Python script, for example?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works